# Yii2 Active form image uploading validation issue at the time of edit

Tags: php, yii2, active-form

I am uploading a file(image and video) using Active form in yii2. At the time of creating validation work great but when I try to open them in edit mode and i already have an image just I'm showing the uploaded image preview.

But when I try to submit the form it is showing please select the image.. I want to skip the validation when I have an image in the preview.

```
echo $form->field($model, 'banner')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
            'options' => ['accept' => 'image/*', 'multiple' => false],
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'initialPreview' => $initial_preview_image,
                'validateInitialCount' => true,
                'initialPreviewAsData' => true,
                'initialPreviewConfig' => $initial_preview_image_config,
                'allowedFileExtensions' => ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'],
                'maxFileCount' => 1,
                'showUpload' => false,
                'showRemove' => $showRemove,
            ],
      //      'pluginEvents' => []
    ]);
```

Comment: use scenarios https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-models and set different rules for update and create

Comment: can you share some example which you really work on